# MySQL query - what is wrong?

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT `tositetuotteet`.`id` , 
       `tuote` , 
       IFNULL( `tositetuotteet`.`hinta` , `tuotteet`.`hinta` ) AS `hinta` , 
       `maara` , 
       `tosite` , 
       `tuotteet`.`nimike`,  
       `verokannat`.`verokanta` 
FROM `tositetuotteet` 
JOIN `tuotteet` ON `tuotteet`.`id` = `tositetuotteet`.`tuote` 
JOIN `verokannat` ON `tuotteet`.`verokanta` = `verokannat`.`verokanta` 
WHERE `tosite` = 1
```

And you can find my MySQL dump [from there](http://pastebin.com/myV3t8J8).

(SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8dd63/1).)

Query returns nothing. It should return

```
| id | tuote | hinta  | maara | tosite | nimike             | verokanta |
| 1  | 1     | 999.99 | 1     | 1      | Esimerkillinen ... | 24        |
```

What is wrong? I just don't get it.

**P.S.** If you know better title for this question, go and edit!

Comment: +1 for giving a complete dump to work with

Comment: Yep, no problemo. There's wasn't anything secret yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your not connecting the correct column

```
SELECT `tositetuotteet`.`id` , 
   `tuote` , 
   IFNULL( `tositetuotteet`.`hinta` , `tuotteet`.`hinta` ) AS `hinta` , 
   `maara` , 
   `tosite` , 
   `tuotteet`.`nimike`,  
   `verokannat`.`verokanta` 
FROM `tositetuotteet` 
JOIN `tuotteet` ON `tuotteet`.`id` = `tositetuotteet`.`tuote` 
JOIN `verokannat` ON `tuotteet`.`verokanta` = `verokannat`.`id` 
WHERE `tosite` = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06192/11

you were connecting  `verokannat`.`verokanta instead of`verokannat`.`id

Comment: Wow, that was little "I am careless" -bug. Thanks still.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be linking to `verokannat` on its id, not its verokanta value - try:

```
SELECT `tositetuotteet`.`id` , 
       `tuote` , 
       IFNULL( `tositetuotteet`.`hinta` , `tuotteet`.`hinta` ) AS `hinta` , 
       `maara` , 
       `tosite` , 
       `tuotteet`.`nimike`,  
       `verokannat`.`verokanta` 
FROM `tositetuotteet` 
JOIN `tuotteet` ON `tuotteet`.`id` = `tositetuotteet`.`tuote` 
JOIN `verokannat` ON `tuotteet`.`verokanta` = `verokannat`.`id` 
WHERE `tosite` = 1
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8dd63/6).

Comment: @PetjaTouru: An upvote is fine (though I did post my answer first - by about 10 seconds!)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` did the trick. `verokanta` is null so JOIN doesn't return data

```
SELECT `tositetuotteet`.`id` , 
       `tuote` , 
       IFNULL( `tositetuotteet`.`hinta` , `tuotteet`.`hinta` ) AS `hinta` , 
       `maara` , 
       `tosite` , 
       `tuotteet`.`nimike`,  
       `verokannat`.`verokanta` 
FROM `tositetuotteet` 
LEFT JOIN `tuotteet` ON `tuotteet`.`id` = `tositetuotteet`.`tuote` 
LEFT JOIN `verokannat` ON `tuotteet`.`verokanta` = `verokannat`.`verokanta` 
WHERE `tosite` = 1;
```